# How to make a table row behave as a hyperlink in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I have a table row that, when clicked, takes the user to a new page:

```
<tr routerLink="/users/{{user.id}}">
  <!-- ... a bunch of cells with user name, etc -->
</tr>
```

That works fine, but as it's not an actual HTML link, it doesn't behave entirely like one in the browser (e.g. there's no option to open the link in a new tab).

I tried wrapping each `<td>` element in an `<a>` and removing the link styling with CSS, which behaves like a link but only when the mouse is over the text in the table cell.

Is there another way to get the table row to behave more like a hyperlink?

Answer (score 8):

Try Like This.

You have to pass array params in order to create dynamic routing URL, Your case will work fine in static URL. Please refer "https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink"

```
<tbody>
  <tr routerLink="[/user, user.id]">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john.doe@abc.com</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: However in this case you won't be able to "cmd+click" or "ctrl+click" to open the page in a new tab

Answer (score 3):

After some research I found the option I like the most. Only do this if you care about native click behaviour such as:

- `CMD + Click`
- `Shift + Click`
- `Right Click + Copy Link`

Here it is:

```html
<table class="table-with-click">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#any-link" class="stretched-link"></a>
       Tim
    </td>
    <td>
       Programmer
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
      <a href="#another-link" class="stretched-link"></a> 
      Job
   </td>
   <td>
      Programmer & IT
   </td>
  </tr>
</tabe>
```

```css
.table-with-click tr {
    position: relative;
}

.stretched-link::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1; /* Or 0, if you have other buttons in your tables */
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

*Note 0: I stole the idea of a `stretched-link` from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/stretched-link/) if you already use Bootstrap you can skip that class.*

*Note 1: You can put the link in any of the `<td>` elements.*

Comment: this does not work in Safari.